# jQuery: finding previous div

Tags: jquery

```
<div class="a" style="display:none">Content 1</div>
<div class="a" style="display:none">Content 2</div>

some other HTML...

<span id="b">foobar</span>
```

How can I match the first div class="a" above the span id="b" to show() it? The id="b" is the only thing I know before.

Comment: You should accept answers for your questions by clicking the hollow check next to an answer.

Comment: What exactly is the structure?   (What parent do they have in common?)

Comment: Did you get something working?

Comment: @SLaks: I don't know which HTML structure is between b and a.

Answer (score 8):

Like this:

```
$('#b').prevAll('.a:first').show();
```

Comment: `prevAll` returns nodes in reverse order, so I write `:first` instead of `:last`.  Note that this will only work if the two elements have the same direct parent.

Comment: This looked weird, so I tested it. Works nicely! jQuery becomes more amazing to me every day.

Comment: The elements dont have the same parent :(

Comment: @powtac: Then you shouldn't suggest they do with your question's code.

Answer (score 3):

```
$("#b").closest(".a").show();
```

Try that.

Comment: maybe there is a div class a closer AFTER the span id b.

Comment: @inkedmn: Wrong.  You're misunderstanding the `closest` method.  http://api.jquery.com/closest/

Comment: It looks like `closest` gives you the nearest ancestor of the current element. It appears that the OP needs the nearest sibling.

Answer (score 0):

Do the elements share an ancestor? If so, you may be able to combine inkedmn's and SLaks's answers:

```
$('#b').closest('parentType').prevAll('.a:first').show();
```

Or something similar, depending on your DOM.

Answer (score 0):

As long as I am understanding multiple selectors correctly, this should work.  It will get all divs with class 'a' and and the span with the id of 'b'.  They will be "in document order" according to the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/).  Then you'll need to get the div prior to your span tag and display it.

```
var elems = $('span#b, div.a');
var divIndex;
for (var i = 0; i < elems.length; i++)
{
    if (elems[i].tagName == "SPAN")
    {
        divIndex = i - 1;
        break;
    }
}

$(elems[divIndex]).show();
```