# How to find this div id?

Tags: jquery, parent

```
<div id="findThisId"></div>

<div id="divID">
    <span id="spanID">
        <p id="pID">p</p>
    </span>
</div>
<br/>
<div id="output"></div>
```

I've been able to get to the parent div of the `<p>` with this:

```
$('#pID').parent().parent().attr('id')
```

but how do then find the previous div id?

http://jsfiddle.net/W5NHH/

Comment: Could you update your HTML with the code from js.fiddle?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work for you

```
$('#pID').closest('div').prev().attr('id');
```

Answer (score 2):

All you need to do is insert a simple `.prev()`:

```
$('#output').html($('#pID').parent().parent().prev().attr('id'));​
```

See the [docs for `.prev()`](http://api.jquery.com/prev/)

A common pitfall with using `.prev()` is that it is really only looking for direct siblings, so one might end up using [`.prevAll()`](http://api.jquery.com/prevAll/) in real world situations.

Comment: Me too :) Just wanted to add this as it isn't 100% clear from the name of the method that it will just look for the next sibling. Been hearing of people going nuts because of this...

Comment: Interesting. I'll make sure to point this out to the juniors.

Comment: The *trouble* starts when you use it with a selector write sth like `$(this).prev('div')` which pretty much feels like "Could I get the previous div please, thanks!"

Answer (score 1):

Joining the party bit late but lil diff here `:)` http://jsfiddle.net/DF8jK/1/

**Parents** API - http://api.jquery.com/parents/

Hope it fits the cause as well. `:)`

This might come handy - [jQuery: finding previous div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2328080/jquery-finding-previous-div)

**code**

```
alert($('#pID').parents('div').prev().html());​
```